# How to add elements beginning in a specific position?

Tags: java, kotlin

I want to add an `array` of `Elements` beginning in an **x** position.

**Given my start list**

`val myList = muttableListOf(1,2,3,4,5)`

**Given my second list**

`val mySecondList = muttableListOf(1,2,3,4,5,5,6,7,8,9)`

I want to merge both lists, and **avoid** repeated numbers like

`val mergedList = muttableListOf(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)`

The list I really want is `val mergedList = muttableListOf(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)`

How can I achieve this without "tricks" to delete repeated elements and doing it by checking if the element are already there? I will add `java` in the **keywords** because both more or less the same list methods.

Comment: Can you alter your example because I don't really understand, at this moment your merged list is equal to second list.

Comment: 1,2,3,4,5 repeats twice on the mergedList

Comment: It isn't clear exactly what you're asking but seems like you could maybe achieve the result by using a [TreeSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) – add all items from list 1 to the set, add all items from list 2 to the set, then use the iterator to get all the items in order. The set itself will handle guarantee that there are no duplicates, so you should end up with `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9`.

Comment: @kaan the elements can be objects that have an id

Comment: in case you need those lists as is (given the accepted answer I assume you don't) you can also use [`distinct`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/distinct.html), i.e.: `val mergedList = (myList + mySecondList).distinct()`

Comment: what did you mean by "beginning in a specific position"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know you are using lists in your question, but if you do not care about order, then you can use sets:

```
val myList = mutableSetOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
val mySecondList = setOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
myList.addAll(mySecondList)
```

If you *do* care about order, then you can use a tree set:

```
val myTree = TreeSet(setOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
val mySet = setOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
myTree.addAll(mySet)
```